# Displaying an image and its metadata in C++

Tags: c++, linux, image, unix

I am learning Linux programming using C++. As a project I want to make program that would pop up a window and display the image (passed as arguments), with the meta data of the file.

I have looked up the [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) library, and I would like to build something similar but simpler, on my own. Basically I want to implement just [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html) kind of functionality. How should I go about doing this?

For a start, I will be working only with .jpg files.

Comment: Look up the Qt framework. It's a great set of libraries that will get your program working very quickly. I believe the command is something like `apt get install qt5-default`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the popup window part can be happen by [QT](https://www1.qt.io/developers/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org)
or many other GUI framework and you should consider GTK too. simple image operation can be done by these too, but for more advance topics you can go for example to [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library

QT sample : http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-tutorials-widgets-toplevel-example.html

SDL sample : https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer

also reading metadata in qt can be done using QImage or [QImageReader](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qimagereader.html) and methods like [QImage::textKeys()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qimage.html#textKeys) or [QImageReader::textKeys()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qimagereader.html#textKeys)

Comment: You could go above and beyond by posting a link to a code example from one of these libraries (Qt has many), installation methods, and linking information.

Comment: @tay10r thanks ... done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement it from scratch, you must know a few things

1. Binary I/O (C++ provides that easily)
2. How Images are stored in computers, what's the difference between different formats like `.jpeg` and `.png` - how they encode and compress pixels ?
3. How to Draw anything on your screen ? there are many options Using a GUI toolkit canvas, X11 windowing system drawing abilities or even use something like OpenGL or DirectX.

Or just simply use any of the libraries mentioned by @nullqube

Answer (score 0):

Qt framework could definitely make your project easier.

It would also allow you to easily display a file dialog window to let the user select the file, rather than passing it as an argument to the program.